# Create button depend on the row of databse how to perform clicked VB

Tags: vb.net

I create button depend on the row on the table, how can i create this

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
```

Help me solve it the code.

```
Dim Check(Row) As Button
    Check(i) = New Button

For i As Integer = 1 To Row

                With Check(i)

                    .Name = "CheckButton" & i
                    .Text = "Check Now"
                    .BackColor = Color.DarkGray
                    .Image = My.Resources.Location_icon__1_
                    .ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                    .ForeColor = Color.Black
                    .Font = New Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", _
                                   8)
                    .Top = 40
                    .Left = 530
                    .Size = New Drawing.Size(158, 77)



                End With

      Panel(i).Controls.Add(Check(i))
Next
```

Comment: What is the question?  This is not a broad scope debugging service.  If you want a new button you created to use that event, you need to use `AddHandler` when you create it to attach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically add a click event you want to use:

```
AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Button_Click
```

Then

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'Your code
End Sub
```

Comment: and can i ask you how retrieve button name when i clicked the button?

Comment: sender.name should give you the button name within the button_click sub